# Return xml json data in react component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, xml, fetch

I am builing my first app in React. I have data in XML file using xml2js converting them to json object abd then i am trying to return title every single AD but without success. I think that may be a problem with this part `.then(data => this.setState({postsList: [data]})`?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {parseString} from 'xml2js'


class AdListing extends Component {

    state = {
        postsList: [],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('export.xml')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(responseText => {
                parseString(responseText, function (err, data) {
                    console.log(data) [1]
                    return data
                })
            })
            .then(data => this.setState({
                postsList: [data]
            }));
    };
    renderList = () => this.state.postsList.map((item, id) => <div>>{item.JOB_TITLE}></div>);

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p>oleole</p>
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default AdListing;
```

[1] Array looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQUB0.png

Comment: yes :( TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Try `.then(data => this.setState({ postsList: data.ADS.AD }));`

Comment: still nothing 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'ADS' of undefined'